# can't install any gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

can't install any gem

ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    dlopen(/Users/MacBookPro/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method
  Referenced from: /Users/MacBookPro/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/openssl.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
 in /Users/MacBookPro/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/openssl.bundle - /Users/MacBookPro/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Comment: What OS do you run and how did you install Ruby?  What command did you run to install the gem?

Comment: I'm using OS X mavericks. I use RVM to install ruby

Comment: Well, rbenv is showing up in your errors.  You should probably delete rbenv if you want to use rvm.

Comment: Did you recently update XCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this problem has to do with a recent update of XCode. After a XCode update you need to do the following steps:

1. Open Xcode and accept the license agreement
2. Reinstall the Command Line Tools.

The second step seems to depend on your OS versions. Try `xcode-select --install` in your console. If that does not work try to start the `Install Command Line Developer Tools` app in `/System/Library/CoreServices`.

After reinstalling the Command Line Tools try to rerun `bundle install`.